# Keep modal open showing WTForms validation errors

Tags: javascript, python, flask, ckeditor, flask-wtforms

I have a form (**WTForms**) which is DataRequired. That form lives in a modal. It is just a textarea field and I have **CKEditor** dealing with it so it shows as a WYSIWYG little text area.
I added to my form the attribute "*novalidate*" because I want the validation error from WTForms to give feedback instead of the ugly popup built in the browser.

**The problem**: my modal closes when I press submit without entering any text.
Is there any jQuery/JS way to keep the modal open showing the validation error instead of letting the modal close and refresh the page before the validation errors give feedback to the user?

This is my modal with the form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="reviewPerfumeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reviewPerfumeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="reviewPerfumeModal">Please Leave a Review</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method=POST action="{{ url_for('reviews.review_perfume', perfume_id=perfume._id) }}" id="form-review">
                    {{ add_review_form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <fieldset class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {% if add_review_form.review.errors %}
                            {{ add_review_form.review(class="form-control form-control-md is-invalid")}}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in add_review_form.review.errors %}
                                <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            {{ add_review_form.review(class="form-control form-control-md ckeditor", placeholder="Review")}}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ add_review_form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S.: This works just fine if the form is not on a modal. I just want to keep the modal open showing the errors.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know a lot about this topic but try this:

```
{% if add_review_form.review.errors %}
<script>
  javascriptFunctionToOpenModal();
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use inline javascript :)

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta If not using inline javscript is a requirement please state that in your post. Also, did the solution forwarded by Puk help?

Comment: Did this solution work? So yes, please press the 'this answer was useful' button :)